# OpenSSL handshake failure with the default enabled cipher in openJdk 8

Tags: java, encryption, openssl

According to the OpenJDK [code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/CipherSuite.java)/documentation, it seems that there is a list of ciphers (close to 50)  enabled by default. My app is built on top of CentOS linux plus OpenJDK and from inside it, I am trying to do an `openssl s_client connect` with a supported and enabled cipher `AES128-GCM-SHA256`.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 0.0.0.0:8443 -cipher AES128-GCM-SHA256
CONNECTED(00000003)
139724265166752:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 99 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1576462403
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

It shows **handshake failure**, which means either the cipher is not present or not enabled which sounds contradictory. How do I proceed to debug on this? My question is is there a way to enable the cipher explicitly to get this openssl handshake working.

Also, if the ciphers are enabled by default, why would openssl handshake fail in the first place?

Will appreciate any suggestions/help.

[Edit]: After connecting with `-debug` flag.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x26d1de0 [0x2715b90] (99 bytes => 99 (0x63))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 5e 01 00 00-5a 03 03 7b 91 0a a7 f0   ....^...Z..{....
0010 - 13 15 3b 09 33 36 ba 3f-a9 ad df b6 6f 5a 30 a7   ..;.36.?....oZ0.
0020 - 22 dc e6 59 a1 d4 a8 14-34 5f 6f 00 00 04 00 9c   "..Y....4_o.....
0030 - 00 ff 01 00 00 2d 00 23-00 00 00 0d 00 20 00 1e   .....-.#..... ..
0040 - 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01-05 02 05 03 04 01 04 02   ................
0050 - 04 03 03 01 03 02 03 03-02 01 02 02 02 03 00 0f   ................
0060 - 00 01 01                                          ...
read from 0x26d1de0 [0x271b0f0] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                              ......(
140413620455328:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 99 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1576463672
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: Have you tried set the `-debug` flag for the `s_client` mode? See `openssl help s_client` for more parameters.

Comment: @Robert, I edited the output with -debug flag.

Comment: In your case the `-msg` parameter seems to be more promising. However from the current dump I would assume that the remote server want's to perform a SSLv3 handshake. I would run a full SSL/TLS + cipher test against the server using https://testssl.sh or if the server is public using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: @Robert Well, while you're at it, I'd in this case suggest `-Djavax.net.debug=all` for the Java side. Beware that this will generate quite a bit of info, but since the handshake seems to fail early it should be OK. More howto [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

Comment: Are you sure you've configured your client correctly? Did you indicate a trust store? I see `no peer certificate available` and `Cipher: 0000`. That would worry me.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, apologies, where do I need to indicate the truststore? Doesn't jdk have a default truststore?
Also, I tried that script, although I couldn't see any option that would tell me what all ciphers are enabled by default.

Comment: I thought that the JDK is the server with the private key and certificate? That certificate needs to be trusted on the client side, using a certificate chain to a certificate in a trust store. I think you need to do some reading up on X.509 certificates used in TLS.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, That's correct. I am running the openssl command in the same host that has private key and cert.